# Why does SQL NOT EXISTS return 1 record of all NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, not-exists

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bae28/1/0) on the following:

```
create table tbl( col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);
insert into tbl values(1,1,1);
insert into tbl values(1,1,1);

select sum(col1) c1, sum(col2) c2, sum(col3)c3
from tbl
where not exists (
  select 2 as c1, 2 as c2, 2 as c3
  )
```

I am expecting this to return 0 records.  Instead it returns 1 record of null values.  Can you tell me why?

P.s. I am trying to understand not exists behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not about the `EXISTS`. Your `NOT EXISTS` evaluates to `FALSE`, since `SELECT 2 AS c1, 2 AS c2, 2 AS c3` always returns a row. This means your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT SUM(col1) c1, SUM(col2) c2, SUM(col3) c3 FROM tbl WHERE 0
```

Saying that, this is actually about the `SUM` semantics. `SUM` even in a empty set should return a value, and the value in this case is `NULL`.

From [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum):

> SUM(expr)
>
> Returns the sum of expr. If the return set has no rows, SUM() returns NULL.
>
> SUM() returns NULL if there were no matching rows.

Comment: Oh,I think I understand now what you are saying ...  the select returns nothing but the SUM function creates the null values..?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what JuniorCompressor pointed, it's important to note the order of execution of SQL clauses within a query. `WHERE` runs first, then the `SELECT` list, where aggregates are being calculated *on an empty result set*, whose result in null, as they got nothing to process.

To actually discard that result as you expect, you would need a `HAVING` clause, which runs afterwards, and it can filter out based on the results of aggregates.

The difference is subtle, but makes the whole point of this question. `WHERE` decides which raw rows qualify to integrate an aggregate. `HAVING` decides which aggregate result to include in the final result.